# Parse.com can't edit channels field

Tags: curl, push, parse-platform, channel

In Data Browser I can't edit the channels field and if I try from terminal with curl

```
curl -X PUT \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxx" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxxx" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "channels": [
      "Promo"
    ]
  }' \
https://api.parse.com/1/installations/mrmBZvsErB
```

give me error: {"code":101,"error":"object not found for update"}. I if try to create new installation class give me error: This class already exists. But if I send push from web console no problem.

Dashboard screen: http://oi60.tinypic.com/dbtmq1.jpg

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seem right. Maybe the problem is the wrong objectId "*mrmBZvsErB*", i suppose you have taken it from parse documentation website (https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-channels/REST)

From your screenshot you should use "**Sdsji0JSYJ**" instead. So:

```
curl -X PUT \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxx" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxxx" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "channels": [
      "Promo"
    ]
  }' \
https://api.parse.com/1/installations/Sdsji0JSYJ
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I've got tried too, but in this case return error:"unauthorized".
I have already written in their forums, but no one answers me ..

Comment: have you tried using the master key instead of rest-api (just for test) ? The key should be "X-Parse-Master-Key" instead of "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" for your app account you should have also that key. Alternatively, you could use also the "X-Parse-Session-Token" of logged user, if you have one

Comment: glad to have helped you ;)